# razor: ignore httprequestvalidationexception

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor, .net-4.0

I am using MVC3 Razor. I want my server to ignore the httprequestvalidation exception. I have tried 
and all codes like [ValidateInput(false)]
none of these codes seem to work with MVC3 .net framework 4.0 razor

Answer (score 0):

```
[ValidateInput(false)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
// ...method body
}
```

Using MVC 3, you must also ensure this is in your Web.config:

```
<system.web><httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" /></system.web>
```